# Inconsistent Asp.net MVC4 (Razor 2.0) Rendering if Write in html attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

In cshtml view (Razor 2.0) I Have got code:

```
<input type="text" value="@if (true) { Write("simpletext"); } " />
```

In Result html generated by Razor 2.0 (MVC4) I have got:

```
<input type="text"simpletext value=" " />
```

In Razor 1.0 (MVC3) code is correct:

```
<input type="text" value="simpletext" />
```

It's seems like render processor wait quotation close, then add attribute to result stream.

How I can configure razor 2.0 to work as razor 1.0 in this case?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try not using the `Write` function, but using the string directly in a ternary if

```
<input type="text" value="@(true ? "simpletext" : "")" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use HTML Helpers provided by Razor? I think this will help out by using HTML Helpers

```
@if (true) { @Html.Encode("SimpleText")}
```